# Android, How to get the height of recycleView before creating the sub viewHolders to remove the scroll

Tags: android

I have a grid recycleView inside a fragment, And I need to know the height of the fragment or the recycleView to config the height of all the sub viewHolders to be  the same, and remove the scrolling.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    if (position <mMonth.calenderDaysTable.length -1) {


        //Some Code here

        //I want to make something like that
        holder.mView.setheight(thisRecycleViewHeight/6);
             // mView is a LinearLayout.
    }
}
```

the Problem is the height of any view is always 0
I need to get the height of the RecycleView before create the sub ViewHolder to calculate the height of each one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your recyclerView is match_parent, you can use smth like

```
DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
float dpHeight = displayMetrics.heightPixels / displayMetrics.density;
```

so then u can `holder.mView.setheight(dpHeight/6);`

Another way is

```
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder = new Holder();
        holder.mView.setheight(parent.getHeight/6);
}
```

Comment: Wooow ! :) 
I didn't know that the parent ViewGroup come with the height.

Answer (score 0):

In onCreateViewHolder, the parent recycle view is passed. You can get the dimensions of your parent by calling getWidth or getHeight to it.